# Quais as vantagens de se passar um function na função "html" do jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Descobri por acidente esses dias atrás que no jQuery é possível passar uma função de callback para a função `html`.

Veja:

```js
$(function ()
{
  $('body').html(function ()
  {
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

E não só isso, mas também para as funções `css`, `prepend`, `append` e etc...

Enfin, eu gostaria de saber quais são os benefícios que eu poderia tirar através dessa funcionalidade do jQuery.

Comment: `$()` selector + `propriedade` - Isso não se auto explica ?

Comment: As vezes costumo fazer perguntas que já sei a resposta pra poder ajudar a ter mais conteúdo no site @Edilson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ideia de ter uma função como argumento é para poder aceder ao conteúdo antes de o alterar. Como que um getter dentro do setter.

Na prática é o mesmo que

```
var valor = $(el).html();
var novoValor = valor + ' algo novo que mude o valor';
$(el).html(novoValor);
```

No caso de `$(el)` ser um conjunto de elementos, o argumento `index` pode ser útil também, nesse a função pode ser ainda mais interessante. Pouparia ter de fazer algo como:

```
$(elementos).each(function(){
    var valor = $(this).html();
    var novoValor = valor + ' algo novo que mude o valor do elemento';
    $(this).html(novoValor);
});
```

podendo ser feito diretamente com:

```
$(elementos).html(function(index, conteudo){
    var novoValor = conteudo + ' algo novo que mude o valor do elemento';
    return novoValor ; // para evitar fazer: $(this).html(novoValor);
});
```

O `this` dentro dessa funçõ callback é uma referência ao objeto iterado/selecionado.